# Transfer Function: State Space for DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, control, transfer-function

General question on making state space equations for a DC motor.
In the link below, why are both the electrical and dynamics equations 3 and 4 used to make a state space eqn.8, instead of combining them together into a single? You could combine them by setting one of the equations to theta_dot, and inserting into the theta_dot the other equation.

http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorSpeed&section=SystemModeling

Comment: Ahh, those are coupled differential equations.  You can't just treat them like algebraic equaitons where you set theta dot equal to y and solve.  (I know next to nothing about driving DC motors.)

Comment: Why can't you? In general coupled equations are left separate because it's difficult to set equal to one variable [eg one equation has sin(theta_dot_dot), another one has tan(theta_dot) ] so they're left separate. But if you can directly say "theta_dot=..." and then plug that into the second equation, it seems like it should work.

Comment: Hi @PB,  OK I guess you can do that.  I'm not sure it helps you though.  I think the rotational speed is one of the parameters you are interested in, so you don't want to eliminate it.  Is this for a class?  (Maybe a TA or professor can help more than I can.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a two state system, so (generically) you cannot replace the coupled
two state system (Equation (8) in your link) by a single first order differential equation.

However, since the system is completely controllable, you can transform the system into controller canonical form and write the system as a single second order differential equation. In this case we can read off the equation from 
the transfer function.

You can see from Equation (7) that we have the system
\$ ((J s+b)(Ls + R) + K^2) \hat{\omega} = K \hat{V}\$, where
\$\hat{\omega}, \hat{V}\$ are the Laplace transforms of the rotational speed and
input voltage respectively. This gives the following differential equation
\$ JL \ddot{\omega}(t) + (JK+bL)\dot{\omega}(t) + (K^2+bK) \omega(t) = K v(t) \$.

It is not clear that this is more convenient that the state space form, but perhaps gives more insight into the rotational dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

> You could combine them by setting one of the equations to theta_dot,
>   and inserting into the theta_dot the other equation

In differential equations you solve for \$\theta(t)\$, not for \$\dot{\theta}(t)\$, and as their values are interconnected the solution is time dependent. For linear differential equations, like the ones in the link, the solution [is an exponential function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Linear_System_Solutions).

In general you could, however, do as you say, but you would get mathematically stuck with a coupled differential equation that's quite difficult to solve. Start by fixing \$\dot{\theta}(t)\$:

$$\dot{\theta}(t) = \frac{K i(t) - J\ddot{\theta}(t)}{b} $$

and then substitute in the other one, getting:

$$ L \frac{di(t)}{dt} + Ri(t) = V - K\frac{K i - J\ddot{\theta}(t)}{b}$$

You need \$\ddot{\theta}(t)\$ to find \$i(t)\$. You can't proceed.

The most common approach to solve the interconnected system for its states' dynamics is to stack the multiple linear differential equations in a single state space (eqs. 8-9 in the link) and [solve it in its matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation).

Your intuition can however be used to find the steady-state (final values, after dynamics) of the system. This is done by setting all derivative to 0 and solving for the states' final values.

Comment: Your comment makes more sense, thanks for writing it out. Regarding your comment "You need θ¨(t) to find i(t). You can't proceed". That second equation is exactly what i was thinking of (Ldi...=V-K(.../b) ; it would have otherwise had theta_dot instead of double-dot. You'd need theta_dot then as well to find i(t), which doesn't seem simpler?

Comment: I see what you mean, but mind that the matrix equation, in that form, solves both equations simultaneously. They are interconnected. It's not that we look for theta_dot rather than theta_dotdot first, but write the whole problem in a different way and solve it altogether. Do you understand my point, now?